# What does "get down on someone" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When watching movies I often heard the women in the movies said "I like him to get down on me". So,

**What does "get down on someone" mean?**

Comment: Are you sure you've heard that right? That sounds like maybe you've mixed that up some. Can you provide an example with an **exact** quote?

Comment: "Get down on" or "go down on"?

Comment: English is not my mother tongue. I am not so sure, but I heard it many times so i don't think i misheard it.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=go+down+on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so there are two possible phrases and you can pick whichever you think it means based on context:

> "Get down on me".

"Get down" can mean "dance" and so it can mean "dance with me".

Here's some of the [lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/koolthegang/getdownonit.html) of a song that has the title "Get Down on It".

> Hey, hey, yeah, what you gonna do? You wanna get down?
>
> Tell me, what you gonna do? Do you wanna get down?
>
> What you gonna do? You wanna get down?
>
> (Get your back up off the wall, dance, come on)
>
> (Get your back up off the wall, dance, come on)

---

There is a possibility that they're actually saying "go down on me".

This is a [euphemism](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=go%20down%20on) for oral sex.

Comment: there is no dancing in these movies i watched, but more likely oral sex. So, maybe "go down on" sounds like "get down on"

Answer (score 1):

Getting down on someone could mean CRITICISE.
For instance,  Lynn's always getting down on the kids.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Means both.  To get down is to boogie ,dance, get groovy , move funky to the music.. Or to go down on someone is to go down there below the bellybutton and get funky with it ,  wash that genital area with your mouth.  Also common sense if your at a dance and someone says come on let's get down .would you expose your privates or dance? Or if your having sex and your partner asks to go down on you would you stand up and dance?